# Laravel: Scheduler not working when specific time is given

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

Trying to schedule command in Larval:

```
$schedule->command('Cname')->everyFiveMinutes(); -- Works just fine
```

But when I give specific day and time like -

```
    $schedule->command('Cname')->weeklyOn(3,'9:10');
or 

    $schedule->command('Cname')->weekly()->thursdays()->at('09:10');

Its not working
```

what am I doing wrong? any thoughts/ suggestions?

Comment: It uses your application's timezone, which by default is set to UTC.  That'd be my first assumption.

Comment: Nice assumption didn't consider that let me try

Comment: Can you show what is in the cron-tab of your system?

Comment: Please run the command `crontab -l` and post the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just use the cron expression * * * * * *

```
$schedule->command('Command Name')->cron('10 9 * * 4');
```

Execute by At 09:10 on Thursdays Weekly

Explanation

```
 * * * * *  command to execute
 ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: Sure, let me try